# Erro numa consulta SQL no PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Estou tendo dificuldades com uma consulta SQL no PHP, quando faço uma consulta obtenho o seguinte erro:

> Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\trabalhowebGustavo\usuario\BancoEndereco.php on line 54

Segue-se o código abaixo da função que retorna o erro:

```
function listaEnderecos($conexao, $filtro, $ordem, $usuario) {
$enderecos = array();
$sql = "select enderecos.*, us.email, cidades.nomecidade 
            from enderecos 
            inner join usuarios us on enderecos.idusuario = us.id
            inner join cidades on cidades.id =  enderecos.idcidade
            where us.email = {$usuario}";
if ($filtro <> "") {
    $sql = $sql .
       " where enderecos.idcidade like '%{$filtro}%'";
}
if ($ordem <> "") {
    $sql = $sql .
       " order by {$ordem}";
}
$resultado = mysqli_query($conexao, $sql );


while ($endereco = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)) {
    array_push($enderecos, $endereco);
}
return $enderecos;
}
```

A linha que informa o erro - `(54)`, é a linha do `while`.
Qualquer dúvida ou informação adicional necessária em relação à pergunta, estou à disposição.

Comment: Se a resposta resolveu o problema, marque ela como aceita. Veja [Como e por que aceitar uma resposta?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1079/91)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean
>   given

Esse erro significa que sua consulta falhou, pois `mysqli_query()` retornou um false(boolean).

Parace que a sua consulta tem um erro de sintaxe, dois `where` na mesma consulta o que deveria ser um `or` ou `and`

```
$sql = "select enderecos.*, us.email, cidades.nomecidade 
            from enderecos 
            inner join usuarios us on enderecos.idusuario = us.id
            inner join cidades on cidades.id =  enderecos.idcidade
            where us.email = {$usuario}"; // primeiro where:
```

Segundo where, aqui caso `$filtro` tem algum valor vai gerar uma consulta com a sintaxe inválida. Acredito que você deve trocar o `where` por um `AND` no if abaixo.

```
if ($filtro <> "") {
    $sql = $sql .
       " where enderecos.idcidade like '%{$filtro}%'";
}
```

Veja uma [exemplo simplificado](http://ideone.com/BooDNQ) de como as consultas foram geradas.